# Собрать все возможные комбинации чисел

Tags: php, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть массив вида:

```
[
[0] => [1, 2, 3],
[1] => [1, 2],
[2] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
];
```

Мне нужно собрать все возможные комбинации чисел, то есть, чтобы получилось:

```
[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 2],
[1, 1, 3],
[1, 1, 4],
[1, 2, 1]... и тд
```

Как это сделать? Может есть пример где посмотреть?

Comment: Я не вникал но вроде похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/334035/Алгоритм-с-перебором-массивов

Comment: То, что Вам нужно, называется `Декартово произведение `(`Cartesian product`). Поищите реализации на php.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас не у компьютера, возможны ошибки. Но навскидку можно например так:

```
$arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
];

$ab = [];
foreach($arr as $row){
    $ab = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($ab, $row)));
}

$result=[];
$k = 1;
$k1 = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ab) * count($ab); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($ab); $j++) {
        $result[$i][] = [$k, $k1, $ab[$j]];
    }
    if($k1 == count($ab)){
        $k++;
        $k1=1;
    }else{
        $k1++;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/4688876) еще есть решение.

```
function get_combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($property => $property_value));
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}
```